# MySQL Create function statement with values and return datatype decimal

Tags: mysql, decimal, create-function

This is my code in MySQL. I should write a statement which calculates the itemavalue by given inventory and price of each item -> inventory*price.
If the itemvalue is negative, then the it should be set 0.

```
CREATE function item_value (inventory int UNSIGNED, price decimal(8,2)) RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
BEGIN 
 IF inventory*price < 0 THEN 
  SET itemvalue = 0
 ELSE 
  SET itemvalue = inventory*price
END IF;
```

I know this isn't working so far, but I have never working with functions in MySQL. Sorry for that, hopefully you guys could help me.

The signature of the function is given:

itemvalue(inventory int UNSIGNED, price decimal(8,2))

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE function item_value (
    inventory int UNSIGNED,
    price decimal(8,2)
) RETURNS DECIMAL(8,2)
BEGIN
    RETURN GREATEST(inventory*price, 0); 
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why are you using DELIMITER and $$?

Comment: @user2379123 . . . The documentation explains this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html.

Comment: Well, I think it would be better to tell you that I have a table called item. It contains all the data like prices and inventories. My function should take the input from the actual inventory and item price and convert it into the itemvalue using formula inventory*price. Is that clearer now?

Comment: @user2379123 . . . This answers the question you asked:  about creating a function in MySQL.  If you have a question that involves updating a table, then that is a different question.  You should ask another question, and provide sample data and desired results.